# Allow calls to most Salesforce APIs from Apex in Unlocked Package

Tags: apex, rest-api, oauth2, unlocked-package

This Apex code from an **Unlocked** Package

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();  
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId()); 
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setEndpoint(baseUrl() + inputs[0].urlIncludingParams);
```

(See [full code here](https://github.com/aquivalabs/my-org-butler/blob/main/force-app/main/default/classes/CallSalesforceApiTool.cls#L8))

tries to make a Callout to the Salesforce REST API

```
GET /services/data/v59.0/sobjects/Opportunity/006Hq00001R7aZFIAZ
```

using the permissions of the user. It works in many orgs but one production org it fails with Status **401**, ErrorCode **INVALID_SESSION_ID** and this message:

```
This session is not valid for use with the REST API.
```

---

**Questions:**

1. Is that because of my use of `GetSessionId()`?
2. But why does it work in Scratch Orgs and Sandboxes?
3. Do I really need to go the route of Connected App, Named Credential and AuthProvider as described in
   https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/beginners-guide-api-calls-from-salesforce-lightning-web-mahawariya/?
4. Is that even packageable?
5. Is there a full example of how they should look exactly?

Would that even work when the My Domain of every org is different and my calls are reaching INTO the APIs of that org?

Comment: What user is used when you make s request?
Make sure it's not "Automated Process User" or any such user as `UserInfo.getSessionId()` would return `null` for them.

Link to doc: https://arc.net/l/quote/qdrgnzet

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're looking at appears when you try to use the REST API from a Lightning Experience context. This is because those sessions have some of the APIs locked down as a security measure. Depending on if you're in Lightning Experience or not would be the difference between why some orgs are working and others are not. It depends on the context you're calling this code from.

The Named Credential/Auth Provider/Connected App is the standard salesforce.com-recommended way of dealing with this issue.

There's a standard loophole that you can still use to avoid this problem. This won't pass a Security Review, but if you're only looking for an Unlocked Package, this will work just fine.

First, start with this simple Visualforce page. Pay careful attention to the whitespace, every break (or not) is intentional.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" 
           applyBodyTag="false" 
           applyHtmlTag="false" 
           contentType="text/plain"
           >{!$Api.Session_Id}</apex:page>
```

Now, you can call this page to get a Visualforce-initiated session ID, which will have full REST API access:

```
String sessionId = Page.sessionId.getContent().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, I know of that loophole but even if my app is not aiming for sec review I would want to try to use the recommended approach. Do you know of any repo or tutorial that describes how to configure and package AuthProvider, Named Credential and Connected App to be able to call arbitrary Salesforce REST APIs?

Comment: @RobertSösemann Not that I'm aware of. I think you could probably script the parts for making the three things you need, but there's no way to package all of it (see the [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage) for more info).

Comment: According to Coverage Report AuthProvider and Named Cred are packagable. And as I heard, the new Named Cred are creatable from Packaged Apex. I also heard that Connected Apps don't need to be packaged. It's just so much that I hoped some existing Open Source repos have done that.

Comment: Strange: I converted the app in this commit (https://github.com/aquivalabs/my-org-butler/commit/afd05f77d58e3a617c35a21efa3da792b96d6521) and in the other orgs it works but in the problematic org it shows "Illegal character(s) in message header value: Bearer"

Comment: There's a new player in town: External Client App, aka  Connected App v2.0. External Client App is packageable: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.external_client_apps.htm&type=5

Comment: @identigral Nice! I'll have to check it out.

Comment: @identigral this is very good news. Would you be willing to convert this to an answer with a little bit of detail so I can a) accept it as answer and b) others can find this?

Comment: @Robert Sösemann Haven't tried them in a package, thus can't answer. This is bleeding edge and likely to have issues. You're better off with whatever works today.

Comment: @identigral I definitely will look into it. Did you find a way to make NamedCreds (old or new), AuthProviders, and Connected Apps work in Unlocked Packages without immersive post-install work or drawbacks?

Comment: @RobertSösemann Last we checked, the scheme that works is to not package the connected app and do everything post-install. New NCs are [APIable](https://github.com/trailheadapps/apex-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/classes/Integration%20Recipes/NamedCredentialRecipes.cls)

Comment: @identigral Does that also work for Unlocked P? Where to create the Connected App and AuthProvider when there is no 1GP packaging org?

Comment: @RobertSösemann Haven't tried it with unlocked but conceptually it should work